# Chrome Blank PDF Print Preview

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, windows-10, print-preview

Looks like print preview for some embed pdf files "application/x-google-chrome-pdf" is not working anymore.
Open [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4eea21rne31ryc1/broken%20pdf.pdf?dl=0) pdf file in Chrome version 59.x and try printing it.
I have Adobe Reader XI version 11.0.20 installed on my system.
Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this post. Basically you will need to delay before print if it is chrome. Kudos to the original post.

[google chrome print preview does not load the page the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343748/google-chrome-print-preview-does-not-load-the-page-the-first-time)

Answer (score 0):

For me the incompatibility issue with chrome 59 seems to be because of the javascript we are injecting to the PDF using QuickPDF library (PageJavaScriptAction).
The JS code is:

```
try{
   print( {bUI: true, bShrinkToFit: true});
} catch(e){
    try{
       print({bUI: true, bShrinkToFit: true});
    } catch(e1){app.alert(e + ',' + e1);}
}
```

After removing this code, the preview seems to be working fine again similar to the older versions of chrome.

Answer (score -3):

1. **Ctrl+a** and **Ctrl+p** will work.
2. Select the data you want to get **print preview** and right click and select the **print** option.