# Printing a html object

Tags: javascript, php

I had read all I could find about this But I am still not able to solve this.

```
<body>
<object data="/app/pdf/banana.pdf" type="application/pdf" 
style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></object>
</body>



<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.print();
    setTimeout("closePrintView()", 3000);
});
function closePrintView() {
    document.location.href = 'somewhere.html';
}
```

Everything is working, Even the redirect when I close the print dialog but the problem is that the print function loads an empty page, I cant see the PDF.

[image: PDF Display Screen]

I tried in every way. I need to open this PDF, Print it and redirect to another page.

Comment: Note that `setTimeout("closePrintView()", 3000);` should be 
`setTimeout(closePrintView, 3000);`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Wrong, open the console and copy-paste `function f(){console.log("hello")};setTimeout("f()",1000);`.

Comment: @leaf I know you *can* use it, but you shouldn't, since it's basically `eval`-ing a string - so much better to put the function name in directly.

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is less ambiguous now, thanks.

Comment: I tried but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<html>
<body>

<object data="cv.pdf" type="application/pdf" 
style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></object>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.print();
    setTimeout(closePrintView(), 3000);
});
function closePrintView() {
    document.location.href = 'somewhere.html';
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. The problem is that that isn't a form. I have to load a saved pdf, print it and redirect somewhere else after printing. It's a business environment, JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: Still not working. Should be a way to open a pdf, print it and close the tab after. Nothing is working. I created the pdf with TCPDF. I just need to print it and go to another page after that.

Comment: read this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343748/google-chrome-print-preview-does-not-load-the-page-the-first-time